# flutter make scrollable widget take remaining space in column widget

Tags: flutter

I have roughly the following code

```dart
Column(
  getWidget1(),
  getWidget2(),
  // Expanded(
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Table(
        children = manyRows()
      )
   // )
  )
)
```

I'm aware that using columns and scrollable is problematic, either throwing constraint errors (due to column providing virtually infinite vertical space, and expanded trying to take all the remaining space or SingleChildScrollViews trying to fit all their content or expanded, which results in an overflow)

How to fit a scrollable inside a column, that take all the space left? currently I'm implementing a workaround using SizedBox with hardcoded height, but it's not sufficient.

Comment: you can use list view and then wrap it with expanded, hope this will work for you..

Comment: why is `Expanded` commented out?

Comment: @TusharPatel, I'll try on Monday

Comment: @pskink, to indicate that I tried to wrap the SingleChildScrollView with an Expanded widget, but the attempt failed to solve the problem.

Comment: no, it works just fine - you must have problem somewhere else, try: `home: Scaffold(
body: Column(
children: [
Text('top widget', textScaleFactor: 2),
Text('widgets below are scrollable'),
Expanded(
child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: [
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
Text('scrollable #$i'),
],
)
)
),
Text('bottom widget', textScaleFactor: 2),
],
),
),`

Comment: I don't know why on Saturday expanded didnt' work, today it did so nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,By wrapping the SingleChildScrollView with Expanded.

```
  Column(
      children: [
        getWidget1(),
        getWidget2(),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Table(
              children: manyRows(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: I used this approach (and commented it out) and it didn't work out, same issue.

Answer (score -1):

**You need to wrap column with `IntrinsicHeight`.**